# Align text and image on the same line?

Tags: graphics, positioning

According to the two-column example document below, how can you put text and image on the same line? I'm interested in how to insert text at `Some text here` and `more text here` with the image right aligned.

Example:

```
|     #TEXT######################### |     #TEXT######################### |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| #################                  | ################################## |
|                                    |                                    |
|                      ************* | ################################## |
|   Some text here     ************* | ################################## |
|                      ************* | ################################## |
|                      **IMAGE.JPG** | ################################## |
|   more text here     ************* |                                    |
|                      ************* | ################################## |
|                      ************* | ################################## |
|                      ************* | ################################## |
|                                    |                                    |
|     #TEXT######################### | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| ################################## | ################################## |
| #################                  | ################################## |
```

Comment: Is "Some text here" and "More text here" the figure caption (you could use the `sidecap` package for that)? Or do you want the main text to wrap around the image (`wrapfig` package)? Or is it completely unrelated text (use a `tabular`)?

Comment: I tried xport's example but it's not exactly what I need. I need precise positioning of `Some text here` & `more text here` including the spacing as depicted above. `wrapfig` should be eliminated then. I'd like to see `sidecap` and `tabular` examples to see which one has better precise text positioning.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the example depicted above is one column out of a two-column document.

Comment: A bit of a random question: Did you make that ASCII mockup of the two column document by hand, or did you generate it using some tool?

Comment: I did it by hand ;-)

Comment: The current title still does NOT reflect you question. It was confusing before seeing the accepted answer. :-)

Comment: You seem to know how the question should be phrased. What title do you recommend to change to? I try to ask questions as accurate as possible. Other times if I don't know how to word the question (like in this case), I mix & match keywords to force a somewhat decent question phrase out so people sorta know what problem I have. If you can phrase this question title better, be my guest ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention the need to precisely position the text, may I suggest using TikZ? Here's an example that uses one node for the image, and two nodes placed using the `positioning` library to have a horizontal gap of 5 mm to the image, with their vertical centers positioned 5 mm and 23 mm below the top of the image:

[image]

The image is taken from [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Normflasche-1.jpg)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

{
\raggedleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (bottle) {\includegraphics{normflasche}};
\node [left=0.5cm of bottle.north west, yshift=-5mm] {Cap};
\node [left=0.5cm of bottle.north west, yshift=-23mm] {Pearls};
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also need the positioning to be dynamic. Meaning if a line is inserted in the paragraph above `Some text here`, the entire layout will will adjust by one line down also. Does the TikZ package allow this?

Comment: Yes, the whole `tikzpicture` environment will move as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

### Development Phase

[image]

### Production Phase

[image]

### Source Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,pst-node}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{center}
{
\endlinechar=-1\relax

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{hen.jpg}}

\newdimen\WIDTH\WIDTH=\linewidth
\newdimen\HEIGHT\HEIGHT=1\ht\IBox

\psset
{
    xunit=0.1\WIDTH,
    yunit=0.1\HEIGHT,
    nodesep=5pt,
    style=gridstyle
}



\pspicture(\WIDTH,\HEIGHT)

% put figure 
\rput[bl]
    (
        \dimexpr\WIDTH-\wd\IBox\relax,
        \dimexpr\HEIGHT-\ht\IBox\relax
    ){\usebox\IBox}

% add an annotation to mouth
\pnode(0.6\WIDTH,0.8\HEIGHT){a}

\rput[rt](0.4\WIDTH,0.8\HEIGHT)
    {
        \rnode[r]{A}{Mouth}
    }
\ncline[linecolor=blue]{->}{A}{a}

% add an annotation to feet
\pnode(0.7\WIDTH,0.1\HEIGHT){b}

\rput[rt](0.4\WIDTH,0.5\HEIGHT)
    {
        \rnode[r]{B}{Feet}
    }
\ncline[linecolor=blue]{->}{B}{b}

% turn of this grid in the production phase!
%\psgrid
\endpspicture
}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on your typesetting preference and eventual goal (personal use, or perhaps publication submission). In addition to using the `wrapfigure` environment from the [`wrapfigure` package](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig), you could use the `minipage` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\newlength{\oldparindent} \setlength{\oldparindent}{\parindent}% Save \parindent
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{tiger}}% Original image
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
  \hskip\oldparindent\lipsum[2]% Text to the left of image
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
  \raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}% Insert image
\end{minipage} \\
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

You could also attempt a layout using the `tabularx` environment - specifically the `X` column type - from the [`tabularx` package](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\smallskip

\newlength{\oldparindent} \setlength{\oldparindent}{\parindent}
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{tiger}}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xc@{}}
  \hskip\oldparindent\lipsum[2] & \raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}%
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{-2ex}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Using minipages to display text and image next to one another]

In case of a document using the `twocolumn` option, using `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` for the `tabularx` example outputs the following:

[image: Using tabularx in twocolumn document to display text and image next to one another]

I understand my vertical spacing is a little hack-ish. However, according to the information provided it might suffice.