# align text and figure on same line

Tags: graphics, formatting

my problem is to align text and figure on the same line. I got the basics from this link placed below (placing of tiger). But i was not able to put a caption and label to the figure as figure environment was not declared. Can someone help me out to caption and label that figure.

[Align text and image on the same line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24685/align-text-and-image-on-the-same-line#)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question seems a bit too vague. Can you supplement it with an example? In any case, you *can* add `\caption` inside `wrapfigure`.

Comment: Try \captionof{figure} from the caption package.