# Problem aligning text and table vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make a page heading using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sidecap,wasysym,array,caption,graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbox{Date: \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
                        \hline
                        & & & & & \\
                        \hline
                        \end{tabular}}
                        \hfill\textbox{\hfil \textsc{\LARGE Content}\hfil}\textbox{\hfill\LARGE\smiley{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

in which I'm trying to make a box using a table, to fill in the date. But the box and the text "Date:" don't seem to align. I already tried doing [Align text and image on the same line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24685/align-text-and-image-on-the-same-line) but I'm not sure if it is the right way to go about it. How can I align the "Date:" and the table in the same line?

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}[b]{...}` or merge 'Date' into table, i.e. `\begin{tabular}{l|*{6}{l|}}{\cline{2-7} Date: & & & & & \\ ... \end{tabular}

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, or simple `\begin{tabular}{...}`, which gives the same result as Heiko Oberdiek answer.

Comment: Yeah, removing the `[t]` alignment from `tabular` gives the same result as Heiko Oberdiek's answer. Thanks @ChristianHupfer and @Zarko :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top element of the table is not the first row, but the line above it.

Usually a tabular row has a strut with `.7\baselineskip` as height and `.3\baselineskip` below (multiplied with `\arraystretch`).
Since digits usually do not have descenders, the following example aligns the table at the bottom line, but moves it down 2/3 of the descender (`.2\baselineskip`) as compromise:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sidecap,wasysym,array,caption,graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,footskip=.5cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand\textbox[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbox{%
  Date: %
  \raisebox{-.2\baselineskip}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      & & & & & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}%
\hfill
\textbox{\hfil \textsc{\LARGE Content}\hfil}%
\textbox{\hfill\LARGE\smiley{}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Didn't know about that regarding the top element of a table, thanks!

Comment: Can the whole pdf be posted as an image like you did in my last question, or do we have to take a screenshot and upload it as an image?

Comment: @VinayakMehta Some time ago, it was possible to upload PDF, which was converted automatically to PNG, but the current upload form only supports "jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp". Usually, I remove the page number at TeX level, run TeX to get the PDF, remove the margins with `pdfcrop` and convert it to PNG (with transparency to remove the white background) via ghostscript. Most of it can be automated by a script.

Comment: Learning something new everyday on TeX.SX! :D